# GC Clojure/Java/JVM memory settings

Tags: java, clojure, garbage-collection, jvm

Hardware setup is 64x 64bit CPUs, 380GB RAM.

Java/Lein settings are:

```
#export JVM_OPTS=-Xmx254g -Xss2g
```

Running a large parallelised Clojure inference algorithm I get

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Yet maximal memory usage by the process is around 30GB.

What settings do I need to change? I do not understand why the GC insists on trying to free up memory - there should be plenty to go around!

When limited to 10GB memory and 10 CPUs, the algorithm does not encounter this problem.

Comment: You need to post your GC log. Otherwise it's hard to tell how the memory was used etc. Just the basic logging would be fine (e.g. `-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:gc.log`).

Comment: Okay, will do - but it might take me a couple hours to run into the issue again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect

```
#export JVM_OPTS=-Xmx254g -Xss2g
```

is a comment.  This means your default heap size of 32 GB (as you have 128+ GB) is being used.  Try removing the `#`  Additionally if `export JVM_OPTS=` appears anywhere after this line, it will override this setting.

Comment: Should I delete the question? It likely won't help anybody - I had #PBS directives above this and accidentally typed that hash in.

Comment: @Oxonon it's up to you. it might be useful to know what happens when no `-Xmx` has been set.